# i don't know how to access to my drupal website ubuntu

Tags: nginx, drupal, devops, drupal-8, drush

I don't know much about Drupal and Drush, but I followed all the instructions and  i was able to put a Drupal project on one of my  servers. The problem now is that I don't know how to access
to the Drupal WebSite.
Does it have a Port number that I should put after localhost or is there another way ??
[image]

Comment: Point your (sub-)domain to the folder where Drupal's index.php resides. That's all.

Comment: how i can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

A simple youtube/google search came up with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RZD_7LevH5I), walk through this 15 min tutorial and you should have Drupal and Nginx set up correctly.

Comment: There is no 0.0.0.0 in my setting.php file how do I make it listen to 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Look in your HTTP-Server settings on which ports the server is listening.

*Example on nginx-server: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf*

You can check and find listening ports:

**shell:**

```
netstat -nal | grep LISTEN
```

```
tcp46      0      0  *.443         *.*              LISTEN     
tcp46      0      0  *.80          *.*              LISTEN
```